# How to get WTF form object data without a POST request?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a template which allows user to enter search parameter (search.html)

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method=”post”>
<dl>
    {{ render_field(form. notificationId) }}
    {{ render_field(form. recordName) }}
</dl>
<div id="searchResults" > </div>
</form>
```

Macro

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

And a template for search results(result.html)

```
{% for notification in content %}
  Result:
  content[notification]['type'] }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

I am using the following ajax request to get search results and display in the above template.The ajax function is called on keyup of both the search fields

```
$.ajax(
    {
      url: ‘result’,
      dataType: "html",
      data:createQueryString(),// gets the value from the dataFields and creates a queryString 
      success: function(data) 
      {
                              $("# searchResults").html(data);      }    });
```

I also I have 2 views one for the searchcriteria section( the section containing the 2 search fields) and one for the search results section.

```
class NotificationSearchView(MethodView):
 def get(self):
   searchform = SearchForm()
   return render_template("search.html”, searchform=searchform)

 @classmethod
 def registerSelf(cls, app):
   NotificationSearchView.app = app
   app.flaskApp.add_url_rule('/search ', view_func=NotificationSearchView.as_view(‘search’))

class NotificationResultView(MethodView):
 def get(self):
   searchform = SearchForm()
   success, content=self.performSearch(searchform) //search method which takes the search parameters and performs the search
   return render_template("result.html”, content=content)

@classmethod
def registerSelf(cls, app):
   NotificationResultView.app = app
   app.flaskApp.add_url_rule('/result', view_func= NotificationResultView.as_view(‘result’))
```

WTF form class

```
from wtforms import Form, TextField 
class SearchForm(BaseForm):
    notificationId = TextField(notificationId)
    recordName = TextField(recordName)
```

The issue which I am facing is that the wtf form object isn’t populated when the ajax call is made to the NotificationResultView, which I believe is because there is no post request fired, but according to my design there is no need of a post request.

I have tried by making the ajax request as post request but even then the wtf form object comes back empty.

Now my only other option is if I pass the search criteria in the query string when making the ajax call, but not sure if that’s the best approach.Please suggest how to proceed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax(
    {
      url: ‘result’,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) 
      {
                              $("# searchResults").html(data);      }    });
```

In your ajax function you aren't sending any data.

update : ok, so you are actually sending data and url is correct.

```
class NotificationResultView(MethodView):
 def get(self):
   searchform = SearchForm()
   success, content=self.performSearch(searchform) //search method which takes the search parameters and performs the search
   return render_template("result.html”, content=content)
```

from above your view function (which is routed to 'result'), your problem is that `searchform = SearchForm()` isn't filled with supplied GET queries.

To solve this you have to supply the values to `searchform`. there are many ways to do it(the most obvious one would be fiddling with form object creation, by `searchform = SearchForm(formdata = request.args)`), and it can be done easier by using flask extension `flask-wtf`.

here is one way to to do it(I'll provide my example since I don't know how you build your query string) :

in html:

```
query_obj = { foo : 'bar', bar : 'baz', answer : 42 };
$.params(query_obj); //foo=bar&bar=baz&answer=42 
/* ajax using above params */
```

with assumption that parameters are successfully supplied to the view:

```
@app.route('/result', method=['GET'])
def fooview():
  foo = request.args.get('foo', '')
  bar = request.args.get('bar', '')
  answer = request.args.get('answer', None, type=int)
  ..
```

hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, while creating the example from my original code i forgot to include that bit. I have updated the question now